# Java. How to get all instance(not class) of subclass with reflected?

Tags: java, reflection, package

Sure, I have do some research like package scan, reflection of java, gson and so on.

## What I want?

I want get some instance randomly but keep this part code in the subclass.

So, each subclass should have a method named like `SuperClass nextInstance()`.
If I get subclass List, say `classes`, by reflection, I just need invoke nextInstance for each element in `classes`.

That's just be done.

But, I need add static method for every subclass, and the name must be `nextInstance`, real stupid!!!

## Why I wanna doing this.

There is a huge test project that I need run.
And each subclass has their own parameters(it is randomly).
I wanna hide the parameters settings.
The co-worker does not need to care what the parameters are.
They just need to care their own code.
I think the only way to implement that, is extend a method from superClass.

## What I have do.

- Create a factory class for each of them(**too troublesome**).
- Add subclass path in a List to loading them in runtime(**Hard to maintain**).
- Try a abstract static method by reflection(impossible in java).
- And so on(may be, I give it up)

## Example

```
    Abstract class SuperClass{
        // I know it is impossible in java, but just explain what I mean.
        public static abstract SuperClass nextInstance();
    }
    class SubClassA extend SuperClass{
        private double params;
        public SuperClass(double parmas){
            this.params = params;
        }
        public static SuperClass nextInstance(){
            return new SubClassA(r.nextDouble()+4);
        }
    }
    class SubClassB extend SuperClass{
        private int params;
        public SuperClass(int parmas){
            this.params = params;
        }
        public static SuperClass nextInstance(){
            return new SubClassB(r.nextInt(20)+4);
        }
    }
    class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            List<Class> classes.....// get classes extend from SuperClass by reflection.
            List<SuperClass> res = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Class c:classes){
                res.add(c.nextInstance())
            }
            // do something on each element in res.
        }
    }
```

## Update

I think I need simpler re-explain what I want to do.
If there anyone has used slfj `LoggerFactory.getLogger(Class c)`,it will be easier to understand.
For me, I need implement a method like `Factory.getInstance(Class c)`, and the code in this method will invoke c.nextInstance();

## Any suggest about it?

Comment: Take a step back from your current situation and please explain what you're trying to achieve in the first place. What do you want to do with every instance of a class?

Comment: @Lino already update

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]. Currently it is still quite unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Don't build test methods into your classes in `src/main/java`, instead put your testing stuff in `src/test/java` and apply it to your classes. Other than that, it's kinda hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Lino Emmm... Is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you can't declare your "public static abstract" method in the super class but you can tell your co-workers just to include a method which is "public static" returns a SuperClass and accepts no arguments and then find that method by reflection in your factory:

```
public static class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Class> classes.....// get classes extend from SuperClass by reflection.
        List<SuperClass> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
            for (Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
                if (isStatic(method) && returnsSuperClass(method) && hasNoParameters(method)) {
                    res.add((SuperClass) method.invoke(null));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasNoParameters(Method method) {
        return method.getParameterTypes().length == 0;
    }

    public static boolean returnsSuperClass(Method method) {
        return SuperClass.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getReturnType());
    }

    public static boolean isStatic(Method method) {
        return (method.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) == Modifier.STATIC;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did, just little bit upset.